# Converting strings within a list into floats

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of numerical values that are of type "string" right now. Some of the elements in this list have more than one value, e.g.:

`AF=['0.056', '0.024, 0.0235', '0.724', '0.932, 0.226, 0.634']`

The other thing is that some of the elements might be a `.`

With that being said, I've been trying to convert the elements of this list into floats (while still conserving the tuple if there's more than one value), but I keep getting the following error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: .`

I've tried a LOT of things to solve this, with the latest one being:

```
for x in AF:
    if "," in x: #if there are multiple values for one AF
        elements= x.split(",")
        for k in elements: #each element of the sub-list
            if k != '.':
                k= map(float, k)
                print(k) #check to see if there are still "."
            else:
                pass
```

But when I run that, I still get the same error. So I printed `k` from the above loop and sure enough, there were still `.` in the list, despite me stating NOT to include those in the string-to-float conversion.

This is my desired output:
`AF=[0.056, [0.024, 0.0235], 0.724, [0.932, 0.226, 0.634]]`

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: @CoryKramer: added it

Comment: so the standalone item `.` should be removed?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: yes, I want the code to ignore standalone `.` when converting the strings into floats

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(l):
    new = []
    for line in l:
        if ',' in line:
            new.append([float(j) for j in line.split(',')])
        else:
            try:
                new.append(float(line))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return new

>>> convert(AF)
[0.056, [0.024, 0.0235], 0.724, [0.932, 0.226, 0.634]]
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try that, I still get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VCF-to-hail-comparison.py", line 320, in <module>
    main()
  File "VCF-to-hail-comparison.py", line 112, in main
    convert(AF)
  File "VCF-to-hail-comparison.py", line 19, in convert
    new.append([float(j) for j in line.split(",")])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
result = []
for item in AF:
    if item != '.':
        values = list(map(float, item.split(', ')))
        result.append(values)
```

You get:

```
[[0.056], [0.024, 0.0235], [0.724], [0.932, 0.226, 0.634]]
```

You can simplify using a comprehension list:

```
result = [list(map(float, item.split(', ')))
          for item in AF
          if item != '.']
```

Answer (score 0):

With `re.findall()` function (on extended input list):

```
import re

AF = ['0.056', '0.024, 0.0235, .', '.', '0.724', '0.932, 0.226, 0.634', '.']
result = []

for s in AF:
    items = re.findall(r'\b\d+\.\d+\b', s)
    if items:
        result.append(float(items[0]) if len(items) == 1 else list(map(float, items)))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[0.056, [0.024, 0.0235], 0.724, [0.932, 0.226, 0.634]]
```